# Deleting a specific In[ ] / Out[ ] pair

Tags: memory, kernel

I recently found that the CleanSlate package allows you to free memory without restarting the Wolfram kernel. The CleanSlate package includes the `ClearInOut`, which resets the `$Line` to 1. However, I wonder if there's a way to clear a specific In/Out pair without deleting every other cell preceding the current one. Is there such a way?

Comment: Can you not just delete the variable using `?Clear` or `?ClearAll` to free up memory?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe something like this?

```
a;
Unprotect /@ {In, Out};
In[1] =.; Out[1] =.;
Protect /@ {In, Out};
DownValues /@ {In, Out}
```

> ```
> {
>   {HoldPattern[In[2]] :> (Unprotect /@ {In, Out}; ), 
>    HoldPattern[In[3]] :> (In[1] =. ; Out[1] =. ; ), 
>    HoldPattern[In[4]] :> (Protect /@ {In, Out}; ), 
>    HoldPattern[In[5]] :> DownValues /@ {In, Out}
>   }, 
>   {HoldPattern[Out[2]] :> {{"In"}, {"Out"}}, 
>    HoldPattern[Out[3]] :> Null, 
>    HoldPattern[Out[4]] :> {{"In"}, {"Out"}}
>   }
> }
> ```

The key part being [`Unset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Unset.html) to only deal with specific `In`s and `Out`s.